# Multiple User VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple User VPN](https://superuser.com/questions/69293/multiple-user-vpn)

I am looking for a cheap or free solution to be able to connect multiple people via VPN to a host computer. Each person should not be able to see what the others are doing while logged in. Is this possible and if so where do I start my hunt?

Update: I was not sure what server, was just thinking of doing it on say a win7 desktop. Just looking into having 2-3 users have access to a multi-user program without each seeing each other. Basically having separate desktop enviroments

Basically, I know nothing and want to know if this is a possibility for me. lol

Comment: All users would be on separate lans, those having a type of remote server almost.  What would be the best way to go about this or a point in the right direction.

Comment: Is Windows a requirement, or just an example?  What types of activities will your users be performing, and what applications will they need to run?

Answer (score 1):

As Journeyman hinted, you'll need a copy of Windows Server running Terminal Services to support multiple concurrent users.  Windows Server also has built-in support for hosting a VPN ("Routing and Remote Access").  Also, setting up a VPN is a good idea, but by no means is it absolutely necessary to do what you want to do.

EDIT: I just thought of another possible solution for Windows.  If you own multiple Windows licenses, you can set up a VMware/VirtualBox/VirtualPC virtual machine for each user.  Use Bridged Networking for each VM to make sure it's on the same LAN as the server.  Then each user can VPN into your network and use Remote Desktop or VNC to connect to their own VM.  The main drawback to using this solution instead of Windows Server is that you'll have to invest a little more in hardware (more RAM, more/faster disks, and possibly a faster CPU) to handle the extra overhead of running several complete Windows instances on one machine and balance out the resource contention.

If you're open to setting up a Linux server, you can configure [remote X sessions](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html) to allow your users to run applications on the main server, but have the apps displayed on the remote clients.  They could all use SSH tunneling to login securely forward the X sessions to their workstations (possibly eliminating the need for a separate VPN, depending on the server's network setup).  Unless you have a Windows-specific application that won't run under WINE, this might do what you need, and the client workstations wouldn't have to be very fast.

Of course, if all you need to run are command-line applications in a terminal, you don't even have to mess around with X, since you can just set up a relatively minimal Linux server and let everyone SSH into it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're confusing a terminal server with a VPN - a VPN connects people outside a lan to a lan, and a terminal server lets people run a programme on another computer on a window. You can probably run something like openVPN for a VPN, but you can't run a terminal server properly on a windows desktop OS.

Answer (score 0):

Well I maybe really off topic here, however what kind of operating System do you want the user's to be using?

If you just want a basic OS then take a look at Webbased OS this: [EyeOs Demo](http://eyeos.info)
And go here to find out more: [EyeOS](http://eyeos.org/)